# Create a plotly line graph where the line is colored by a category?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I need to create a simple plotly line graph that is colored by a categorical column of data. The data is time series data that needs to be colored by a category. Does anyone know how to set a color category in a simple line graph or a time series graph by a category using python plotly api?

x_axes    - time data 
y_axes    - depth data from 0' to 5000'
category  - on_bottom, off_bottom, drilling, etc.

Example of the output would be the below graph, that is colored by the category column as listed above?

[Plotly Python - Time Series Graph Example](https://plot.ly/python/time-series/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the data and show them in different traces in the graph. You can do this by using [`DataFrame Subsetting`](http://chris.friedline.net/2015-12-15-rutgers/lessons/python2/02-index-slice-subset.html). The main line that does the subsetting is as so.

```
df[df['direction'] == 'Increasing']['AAPL.Open']
```

In the section `df[df['direction'] == 'Increasing']` what happens is that, we check if the `direction` column of the dataframe is equal to `Increasing` value/category, if true, then the dataframe is subsetted so that only those values are present, then we can pick a specific column to plot by selecting the column using the part `['AAPL.Open']`

Please refer the below example and let me know if your issue is resolved!

**Code:**

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, plot
from plotly import tools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

opening_increasing = go.Scatter(
                x=df.Date,
                y=df[df['direction'] == 'Increasing']['AAPL.Open'],
                name = "AAPL Opening Price - Increasing",
                line = dict(color = '#17BECF'),
                opacity = 0.8)

opening_decreasing = go.Scatter(
                x=df.Date,
                y=df[df['direction'] == 'Decreasing']['AAPL.Open'],
                name = "AAPL Opening Price - Decreasing",
                line = dict(color = '#7F7F7F'),
                opacity = 0.8)

data = [opening_increasing, opening_decreasing]

layout = dict(
    title = "Apple Opening Price by Increasing/Decreasing Categories of Direction"
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename = "Manually Set Range")
```

**Output:**

[image]